# iOS TextField Validation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need a way to ensure that phone numbers have 10 digits with no other characters ie () - and make sure that email addresses are valid emails (formatted correctly).

Is there any library that can't make this easy for me so I don't have to write regular expressions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will check a UITextField for a proper email and phone number of 10 digits or less.
Add this method to the [textFields *delegate*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) then check if the characters it is about to change should be added or not.
Return `YES` or `NO` depending on the text field, how many characters are currently in it, and what characters it wants to add:

```
#define ALPHA                   @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#define NUMERIC                 @"1234567890"
#define ALPHA_NUMERIC           ALPHA NUMERIC

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput = nil;
    switch (textField.tag) {
        // Assuming EMAIL_TextField.tag == 1001
        case 1001:
            if ([[textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] count] > 1)
                unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[ALPHA_NUMERIC stringByAppendingString:@".-"]] invertedSet];
            else
                unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[ALPHA_NUMERIC stringByAppendingString:@".!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@"]] invertedSet];
            break;
        // Assuming PHONE_textField.tag == 1002
        case 1002:
            if (textField.text.length + string.length > 10) {
                return NO;
            }
            unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
            break;
        default:
            unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet illegalCharacterSet] invertedSet];
            break;
    }
    return ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unacceptedInput] count] <= 1);
}
```

---

Also, check out these 2 articles:
[Auto-formatting phone number UITextField on the iPhone](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/auto-formatting-phone-number.html)
[PhoneNumberFormatter](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html).

Comment: Looks good, I haven't looked into the text field delegate before.

Comment: chown, this works great but doesn't seem to handle delete key events. Returns NO if phone is >= 10 therefore doesn't change upon delete

Comment: Oh, you are correct.  Replace `if (textField.text.length >= 10)` with `if (textField.text.length + string.length > 10)`

Comment: Using tags (magic numbers) to distinguish your views is not a very clever code. Why not just compare "textField == self.emailInput" assuming you have two properties self.emailInput and self.phoneInput? Code will be easier to read and less prone to errors. Also, in general, regular expressions would give you better results: "[0-9]{10}" for phone numbers and something like "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.0-9]{2,30}@([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,3} for emails. Note that I didn't check the email regexp, it's just something that could possibly work and I don't remember how exactly it should look like.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way of ensuring phonenumber length in the UIViewController that has the text field in it's view.

```
- (void)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    if ([[[self phoneNumberField] text] length] > 10) {
        [[self phoneNumberField] setText:[[[self phoneNumberField] text] 
          substringToIndex:10]]; 
    } 
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self phoneNumberField] addTarget:self 
                            action:@selector(valueChanged:) 
                            forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}
```

For emails I suppose you want to check against a regexp when it loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Simple Example for UITextField Validation while type in keyboard other characters not displaying

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
//UITextField *tf_phonenumber,*tf_userid;
if (textField.text<=10) {
char c=*[string UTF8String];
if (tf_phonenumber==textField)      //PhoneNumber /Mobile Number
{
    if ((c>='0' && c<='9')||(c==nil)) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
if (tf_userid==textField)           //UserID validation
{
    if ((c>='a' && c<='z')||(c>='A' && c<='Z')||(c==' ')||(c==nil)) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
    return YES;
}
else{
    return NO;
}
}
```