# Password validation in UITextField in iOS

Tags: objective-c, validation, ios5, passwords, uitextfield

I have 1 `UITextfield` for password in my iPhone application.

I want to validate this textfield with the following validation.

- Must be at least 10 characters
- Must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character
- Valid special characters are – `@#$%^&+=^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$`

How can I restrict the `UITextField` with above requirements?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how I would do it. The validation should be done at the end when the user has typed in the password and not in between.I will not be using `NSRegularExpression`.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   int numberofCharacters = 0;
   BOOL lowerCaseLetter,upperCaseLetter,digit,specialCharacter = 0;
   if([textField.text length] >= 10)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < [textfield.text length]; i++) 
      {
         unichar c = [textfield.text characterAtIndex:i];
         if(!lowerCaseLetter)
         {
           lowerCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
         }
         if(!upperCaseLetter)
         {
           upperCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
         }
         if(!digit)
         {
            digit = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
         }
         if(!specialCharacter)
         {
            specialCharacter = [[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
         }
      }

      if(specialCharacter && digit && lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter)
      {
         //do what u want
      }
      else
      { 
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Please Ensure that you have at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character"
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
      }

   }
   else
   {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Please Enter at least 10 password"
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
   }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 18):

You can also do this by using `Regex`. Here are few example I am providing for you:

```
// *** Validation for Password ***

    // "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$" --> (Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet and 1 Number)
    // "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,16}$" --> (Minimum 8 and Maximum 16 characters at least 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character)
    // "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,}$" --> (Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet and 1 Number)
    // "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}" --> (Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character)
    // "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&]{8,10}" --> (Minimum 8 and Maximum 10 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character)
```

***Fourth*** from the list is your case, following code snippet shows how to use it:

```
-(BOOL)isValidPassword:(NSString *)passwordString
{
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&]{10,}";
    NSPredicate *passwordTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stricterFilterString];
    return [passwordTest evaluateWithObject:passwordString];
}
```

*Using the method:*

```
if(![self isValidPassword:txtPassword.text]) {
    /* Show alert: "Password must be minimum 10 characters,
       at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 
       1 Number and 1 Special Character" */
}
else {
    // Password is valid
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**Condition**: Password should contain atleast 8 characters, 1 uppercase and 1 number

**Solution in Swift 3**

you can write **String Extension** like this,

```
extension String {
    func isValidPassword() -> Bool {
        let regularExpression = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"
        let passwordValidation = NSPredicate.init(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regularExpression)

        return passwordValidation.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}

//Example 1

var password = "@Abcdef011" //string from UITextField (Password)
password.isValidPassword() // -> true

//Example 2

var password = "Abcdef011" //string from UITextField 
password.isValidPassword() // -> false
```

or you can write function like this,

```
func validate(password: String) -> Bool
{
    let regularExpression = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"

    let passwordValidation = NSPredicate.init(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regularExpression)

    return passwordValidation.evaluate(with: password)
}
```

this will give you the same result.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

check if password is strong ?

1. length more than or equal 8
2. lowercase
3. uppercase
4. decimal Digits
5. special characters like !@#$%^&*()_-+ is optional

   **Why i not use regular expression ?**

   **Because it's difficult to support reserved characters in regular
   expression syntax.**

---

```
 func isValidated(_ password: String) -> Bool {
     var lowerCaseLetter: Bool = false
     var upperCaseLetter: Bool = false
     var digit: Bool = false
     var specialCharacter: Bool = false

     if password.characters.count  >= 8 {
         for char in password.unicodeScalars {
             if !lowerCaseLetter {
                 lowerCaseLetter = CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters.contains(char)
             }
             if !upperCaseLetter {
                 upperCaseLetter = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.contains(char)
             }
             if !digit {
                 digit = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(char)
             }
             if !specialCharacter {
                 specialCharacter = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.contains(char)
             }
         }
         if specialCharacter || (digit && lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter) {
             //do what u want
             return true
         }
         else {
             return false
         }
     }
     return false
 }
 let isVaildPass:Bool = isValidated("Test**00+-")
 print(isVaildPass)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can verify your password validation using the below function just pass a password string and this will return you BOOL value.

```
-(BOOL) isPasswordValid:(NSString *)pwd {

    NSCharacterSet *upperCaseChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
    NSCharacterSet *lowerCaseChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];

    //NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

    if ( [pwd length]<6 || [pwd length]>20 )
        return NO;  // too long or too short
    NSRange rang;
    rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
    if ( !rang.length )
        return NO;  // no letter
    rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
    if ( !rang.length )
        return NO;  // no number;
    rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:upperCaseChars];
     if ( !rang.length )
         return NO;  // no uppercase letter;
    rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:lowerCaseChars];
    if ( !rang.length )
        return NO;  // no lowerCase Chars;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

for me Best way was to use `NSPredicate` and regex.
this is regex for your case: `^(?=.{10,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([@#$%^&=a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$`

[image: image created on debuggex.com]

objective C code:

```
NSString *regex = @"^(?=.{10,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([@#$%^&=a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$";

NSPredicate *passwordTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

BOOL isValid = [passwordTest evaluateWithObject:yourTextfield.text];
```

Answer (score 2):

use a regex (NSRegularExpression class has docs on how to write the patten itself) and then :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    //delete
    if (string.length == 0) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (self.regEx) {
        NSMutableString* check = [NSMutableString stringWithString:theTextField.text];
        [check replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSTextCheckingResult* match = [self.regEx firstMatchInString:check options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [check length])];
        if (match.range.length != check.length) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
}
```

**Warning: Restricting the input this way is really confusing for users. You type and type and the character you type just doesnt appear!**

I'd maybe go with a small red (!) next to the test field but I'd always allow the input itself!

Comment: "Restricting the input this way is really confusing for users."  -- particularly in a hidden password field!

Answer (score 2):

I have this elegant solution for Forms (like sign-up) where you have a lot of validation

I have in my custom UITextField  the outlet:

```
@IBInspectable var regexpValidation: String? = nil
```

In storyboard I can access it through attribute inspector and put regexp string like that (for email):

`[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?`

then in my subclass I have this computed var:

@IBInspectable var regexpValidation: String? = nil // Optional, Set this in InterfaceBuilder

```
var inputIsValid: Bool {
    get {
        if let expr = regexpValidation {
           return (text.rangeOfString(expr, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil)
        } else {
            return true
        }

    }
}
```

which could be used like this:

```
   override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        if (inputIsValid) {
            return super.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        else {
            text = ""
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your validation code in this delegate method of `UITextField`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Few links that you might want to refer for implementation

[how to use regular expression in iOS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206144/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-ios-sdk)

[iOS TextField Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665323/ios-textfield-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `control:isValidObject:` method of the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol which allows you to validate the value of a NSTextField.  Assuming you have all your interface builder bits and pieces configured correctly, you might do something like this:

```
@interface PreferencesController : NSWindowController <NSTextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *username, *password;
}

@end

@implementation PreferencesController

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control isValidObject:(id)object
{
    if (control == password) {
      // Perform validation and return YES or NO
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: isn't this fired AFTER input? He wants to restrict the input.... IF it is called bore, this is cool :)

Comment: It is indeed fired after the input.  I didn't read the question as restricting the key presses during input.  That would be really confusing for the user, I think.

Comment: it is confusing - and I speak from experience :D ill add that to my answer

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 5 USING RXSWIFT, a better, neat and reactive approach.

validate password function will be like this, Obviously you can add as many conditions as you want as per your requirement.

```
 func validatePassword(password: String) -> (Bool, String) {
  //Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet and 1 Number:
var tuple: (Bool, String) = (true, "")
var string = "Requires atleast"

if(password.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters) == nil){
    string = "uppercase"
    tuple = (false, string)

}
if(password.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) == nil){
    string += ", number"
       tuple = (false, string)

   }
if(password.count < 8 ){
    string += ", 8 chars"
       tuple = (false, string)

   }
return tuple }


 func isPasswordValid(in string: String) -> Observable<(Bool, String)> {
    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in

        let tuple = self.validation.validatePasswordForSymbol(password: string)

        observer.onNext(tuple)


        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

You can use aforementioned function in viewModel or VC as per your architecture.
Then invoke the same function like below in your VC.

```
passwordTextField.rx.text
            .orEmpty //1
            .filter { $0.count >= 1 } //2
            .flatMap { self.isPasswordValid(in: $0) }
            .subscribe(onNext: { result in
                print("Valid password", result)
                //update UI here 
                // result will be like (false, "Requires atleast, 8 chars, number")
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```