# TextField uppercase and lowercase validation

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on textfields validations and getting confused how to validate textfield must contain at least 1 character from all of the following categories:
English uppercase characters (A - Z).
English lowercase characters (a - z).

Comment: What's confusing? Where's your code?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132276/password-validation-in-uitextfield-in-ios/15158351 might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `CharacterSet`s (described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset))

You can create various Character sets (lowercase letters for instance) and test whether a string has content that matches said character set.

So, you could create a function which returns a boolean. The function checks your string against two `CharacterSet`s and only if both can be found in the string, does the function return `true`.

Something like this

```
func validate(string: String) -> Bool {
    let lowercase = CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters
    let uppercase = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters

    let lowercaseRange = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: lowercase)
    let uppercaseRange = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: uppercase)

    return lowercaseRange != nil && uppercaseRange != nil
}

validate(string: "Hello") //returns true
validate(string: "hello") //returns false
validate(string: "HELLO") //returns false
```

Have a look at [this article](https://nshipster.com/characterset/) from NSHipster to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Credit : [TextField uppercase and lowercase validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132276/%E2%80%A6)

Here is the regext for the condition :- Minimum 8 characters, 1 uppercase and 1 number.

**^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}**

```
extension String {
func isValidPassword() -> Bool {
    let regularExpression = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"
    let passwordValidation = NSPredicate.init(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regularExpression)

    return passwordValidation.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}

//Example 1

var password = "@Abcdef011" //string from UITextField (Password)
password.isValidPassword() // -> true

//Example 2

var password = "wer011" //string from UITextField 
password.isValidPassword() // -> false
```

Comment: credit where credit is due: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40526112/4063602

Answer (score 0):

```
func isValidPassword(testStr:String?) -> Bool {
    guard testStr != nil else { return false }
 
    // at least one uppercase, 
    // at least one lowercase
    // 8 characters total
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}")
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple extension accepts **any** `CharacterSet` to check:

```
extension String {
    func hasCharacter(in characterSet: CharacterSet) -> Bool {
        return rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) != nil
    }
}
```

usage:

```
"aBc".hasCharacter(in: .lowercaseLetters)
"aBc".hasCharacter(in: .uppercaseLetters)
```